# Flink Python API java.io.EOFException

Tags: apache-flink

I'm coding three Batch Applications, with the Python API, however, my third application is dealing with some Exceptions, especially when I increase the parallelism. This application has a Cross transformation inside it.

The cluster has 4 VMs, with 4 cpu cores and 7GB RAM each machine. So, the max parallelism setted 16.

The exception is:

```
 org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Job execution failed.  
    atorg.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:427)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:101)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:400)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:387)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)  
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:926)  
    at org.apache.flink.python.api.PythonPlanBinder.runPlan(PythonPlanBinder.java:149)  
    at org.apache.flink.python.api.PythonPlanBinder.main(PythonPlanBinder.java:114)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:419)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:339)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:831)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:256)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1073)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1120)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1117)  
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)  
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)  
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)  
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1116)  
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:900)  
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:843)  
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:843)  
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)  
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)  
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)  
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)  
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)  
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)  
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)  
    at org.apache.flink.python.api.streaming.data.PythonStreamer.streamBufferWithoutGroups(PythonStreamer.java:252)    
    at org.apache.flink.python.api.functions.PythonMapPartition.mapPartition(PythonMapPartition.java:54)  
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.MapPartitionDriver.run(MapPartitionDriver.java:103)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:490)  
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:355)  
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:655)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've got some evidences:
1) It's not at all deterministic, eventually, the application finished without errors.
2) With parallelism <= 4 the algorithm finish flawlessly, exception often happens with higher parallelism degrees.
3) Even entering small inputs (~20MB) the exception occurr.
4) I didn't find any error at the slaves logs (jobmanager), only at the Master Flink Taskmanager

Can you help to find out the responsible for this? I can get more logs (namenode, datanode, jobmanager, taskmanager) if necessary.

Comment: Which version of flink are you using? The python version would also be interesting. The exception implies that the python process shuts down neither cleanly nor with an error, which is rather odd. I will try to reproduce this tomorrow. If you're willing to debug this yourself you can modify the catch block PythonStreamer#streamBufferWithoutGroups method to catch all exceptions. This way, if an error occurred in the python process it should be included in the exception message.

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler I'm using Flink latest stable version: 1.2.0. Hadoop: 2.7.3 and Python: 3.5.2.

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler If you'd like to access the Taskmanager raw log, I uploaded to: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4GPJsnWQ1FXM3JNeWxnVFFuc0U/view?usp=sharing

My application source code is called CalculateSimilarity.py and is available at git: https://github.com/matheusmig/Flink-Minimantics/tree/master/Python%20Package/Minimantics

Comment: Maybe my Python code is throwing some exception and i'm not catching it? I'll improve the exception handle at python level on my application. If it doesn't work, I'll try to build the Flink from source and do the modifications at java PythonStreamer

Comment: The entire user-defined function execution is wrapped in a try-except block; all exceptions should be handled by Flink. But the error detection/reporting is a bit brittle :/